# If a complex function has derivative 0 then it's constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to prove that if a complex function $u(x,y)$ has partial derivatives $u_x$ and $u_y$ that vanish at every point in a region $D$, then $u$ is constant in $D$.  (Stated and proved in Bak's *Complex Analysis*, but I don't understand some of the proof.)  A region is defined to be an open connected set.

Suppose $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are two points in $D$.  We have a proof from earlier that a region is polygonally connected, so suppose that the sequence $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$ is a sequence of vertices of a polygon that connects these two points.  Bak writes that any two successive vertices represent end-points of a horizontal or vertical segment, but I fail to see why that would be so.  I'm imagining some region in $\mathbb{C}$ on which the function is defined, this region could be some open connected blob, and the polygonal path from one point in it to another is some collection of diagonal lines.  Is the idea that, even if the lines are diagonal, we could make small enough vertical and horizontal segments that stay in $D$ and still contain $v_1, ..., v_n$?

Comment: If you want to move from $(1,1)$ to $(2,2)$ you may pass through $(1,1)-(2,1)-(2,2)$, no!

Comment: Yes, if you can move from one point to another along some lines, then you сan move along horizontal and vertical segments.  Yes, you can approximate any line with another combination of small horizontal and vertical.

Comment: @MyGlasses but the challenge is, will $(2,1)$ necessarily still be in $D$?

Comment: Yes. The path in the proof must necessarily be in domain!

Comment: Yes, so ... it seems the proof has a gap if this is the strategy.